# Add color to a single line of a display field

Tags: extjs

I have this piece of code where I need to add color to a single line in a display field. how do i do that?

```
var text = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Display', {
        fieldStyle: 'font-weight: bold; color:  #00a8d0',
        value : 'value  1' + '<br>' + 'value 2'
    });
```

By doing this, both value 1 and value 2 is colored. but i want just value 1 to be colred. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just wrap the items in a div:

```
var text = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Display', {
    renderTo: document.body,
    value: '<div style="font-weight: bold; color:  #00a8d0;">value 1</div><div>value 2</div>'
});
```

Comment: Yes, This is perfect. We should put effort on styling, not on unstyle.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1slj&view/editor).Here please give some class name from css file and add these styling there.Reply if any issues.Any update

Comment: Why do this? Go to the effort of styling everything to then unstyle it?